# IceFaces 1.8.2a

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Would anyone have any insight on getting icefaces 1.8.2 to run in Glassfish 3?  I have read that a version of Glassfish exists (1.8.2a) that would work but I cannot find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you've have to swap out the JSF libraries from JSF 2 (which is what is supplied as part of GF3) to JSF 1.2 (which is what ICEfaces 1.8 uses).  This might be a bit fiddly.

It looks like you need the 1.8.2a release, which has some fixes to enable this, as well.  It also looks like it's not freely-downloadable.  If you have a ICEfacesEE subscription, you can get it, but it's not open source.  Unless this has changed.  Version 1.8 of ICEfaces is fairly old now, and they don't list anything before v2 on their pages.

Good luck